# Issue making toolbar with custom height | Swift 5

Tags: swift, toolbar

Essentially I have the following toolbar that is currently set to contain two buttons on both the left and right side:

```
//Select All Toolbar
self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "tabBarColor")
//self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
self.navigationController?.toolbar.sizeToFit() // without this line it doesn't work
self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor(named:"toolBarRedColor")
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

let selectbutton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(printMe))

let unselectbutton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(printMe))

items.append(selectbutton)
items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))
items.append(unselectbutton)
self.toolbarItems = items
```

I would like to expand the height of the tool bar and have tried doing the following:

```
class CustomToolbar: UIToolbar {

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

    var newSize: CGSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    newSize.height = 80  // there to set your toolbar height

    return newSize
    }

}
```

What is being done incorrectly? The height is not being adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let navBarSize = CGSize(width: navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.width, height: 200)

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navBarSize.width, height: navBarSize.height)
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Where would this go? In the custom class?

Comment: Try and add it in the ViewController where you display the NavBar.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of your code? It's hard when I can't see the overall structure :)